# Unable to run a standlone scala file

Tags: scala, scripting

I'm following examples out of Programming in Scala book by Odersky and I'm unable to run a simple standalone scala file with `scala hello.scala`. When I do this, I get this error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class hello.scala
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hello.scala
```

I'm using scala3.

Here's a state of my file and commands I'm running.

[image]

Comment: What exact version of Scala 3 are you using? I think support for `scala hello.scala` wasn't re-added until Scala 3.1.

Comment: Please don't use screenshots to post code or transcripts; it makes it more difficult to help you, since we can't copy-and-paste to try it ourselves.

Answer (score 2):

If you follow the steps from [the documentation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/book/methods-main-methods.html) you'll see that you need to compile your file before running it.

If you run:

```
scalac hello.scala
scala hello
```

You should get the result you want.

Answer (score 0):

you might consider using the new (and excellent) tool from virtuslab called 'scala-cli': https://scala-cli.virtuslab.org/

Comment: I would not (as of November 2021) recommend this to language newcomers yet; it's still very much under development.